# Bottle() w/ Beaker Middleware?

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

How do you use bottle subapps with beaker Sessions?

bottlepy.org shows examples for both:

**Sub-apps**
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#plugins-and-sub-applications

**Sessions**
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#keeping-track-of-sessions

**Combined**

```
from bottle import Bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}

app = Bottle()
app = SessionMiddleware(app, session_opts)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'

app.run()
```

This kicks out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "example.py", line 14, in <module>
 @app.route('/')
 AttributeError: 'SessionMiddleware' object has no attribute 'route'
```

Comment: I should have included that the objective here is to be able to .mount subapps while still having session support through beaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided here: https://github.com/bbangert/beaker/issues/79#issuecomment-89769806

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to execute exactly the same code as in the tutorial?

```
import bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}
app = SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)

@bottle.route('/test')
def test():
  s = bottle.request.environ.get('beaker.session')
  s['test'] = s.get('test',0) + 1
  s.save()
  return 'Test counter: %d' % s['test']

bottle.run(app=app)
```

Comment: Yes, but then I can't app.mount subapps. Everything I read about subapps indicates having a Bottle() object to be able to .mount.

Answer (score 1):

so a slight warning about using `beaker.SessionMiddleware`. it writes the entire session on every request that reads it.  we discovered this when using a multithreaded server, as writes to it were being lost (due to the obvious race condition).  we wrote a drop-in replacement (same API) for it because of this.  it's available here: https://github.com/keredson/drsession

Comment: absolutely and exactly what I needed. 1000 thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import bottle
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session = {
    'session.type': 'file',
    'session.cookie_expires': 300,
    'session.data_dir': './data',
    'session.auto': True
}
main_app = bottle.Bottle()
sub_app = bottle.Bottle()

app = SessionMiddleware(main_app, session)

@main_app.route('/')
def index():
     return 'This is app'

@sub_app.route('/')
def sub_app_index():
    return 'This is subapp'

main_app.mount('/sub', sub_app)

bottle.run(app=app)
```

Also you can import your subapp from separate module

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one bottle app in your script, you can use `@route` instead of `@app.route`